# What errors does FileManager throw?

Tags: swift, error-handling, nsfilemanager, foundation

What are all the errors that can be thrown by `FileManager`'s methods? Specifically, I'm interested in the errors throwable by [`attributesOfItem(atPath:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1410452-attributesofitem).

This is how I want to use it:

```swift
do {
    let inode = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: somePath)[.systemFileNumber]
} catch SomeError.someSpecificError (let someContext) {
    /* implementation omitted... */
}
```

Comment: Using `try?` it will never throw anything. It will return an optional instead of throwing the error. What you need is to use `try` and simply `} catch { print(error) }`

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks for pointing it out. It was a typo. I intended to write `try` instead of `try?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be like the following (see more file related constants in documentation for `CocoaError`)

```
do {
    let inode = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: somePath)[.systemFileNumber]
} catch CocoaError.fileNoSuchFile {
    print("Error: no such file exists")
} catch CocoaError.fileReadNoPermission {
    print("Error: you don't have permissions")
} catch {
    // something unknown
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I read `CocoaError`'s [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/cocoaerror) and [source](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/392baefc47d20b56fa685216677160de0f86a134/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/NSError.swift#L623), but they don't explain what the `rawValue`s are. Is there any meaning behind each `rawValue`, or is it just a code to differentiate the errors?

Comment: @Wowbaggerandhisliquidlunch, in majority of cases you don't need rawValue, the named code is that as described, in mostly self-descriptive. If some unnamed code happen, for any reason, the it rather will be needed to `catch let error as NSError`, ie. generic way, and read domain and code from there.